# Excel VBA: Detect what slicers were selected and store into an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Is there a more efficient way to detect/listen to what a user has chosen in a slicer? I want to store their selections into an array, preferably by their given sliceritem name and not determined by me.  In this example the slicers are limited to just 3, but in my actual worksheet there will be 10-20 each.

[image]

```
Function slicerReader()
Dim slicerArray(2) As Variant ' 0 for Age, 1 for State
Worksheets(1).Select
 If ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Age").SlicerItems("20").Selected = True And ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Age").SlicerItems("20").Selected = True And ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Age").SlicerItems("30").Selected = True Then
slicerArray(0) = "All"
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Age").SlicerItems("20").Selected = True Then
slicerArray(0) = 20
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Age").SlicerItems("25").Selected = True Then
slicerArray(0) = 25
Else
slicerArray(0) = 30
End If

Debug.Print slicerArray(0)


If ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_State").SlicerItems("California").Selected = True And ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_State").SlicerItems("Florida").Selected = True And ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_State").SlicerItems("Texas").Selected = True Then
slicerArray(1) = "All"
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_State").SlicerItems("California").Selected = True Then
slicerArray(1) = "California"
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_State").SlicerItems("Florida").Selected = True Then
slicerArray(1) = "Florida"
Else
slicerArray(1) = "Texas"
End If
Debug.Print slicerArray(1)

slicerReader = slicerArray

End Function
```

This code is obviously not going to work because there is still a possibility for a user to select combinations of slicers (1,3) or (2,3) etc

Is there any possible way to loop through each sliceritem and check if they're true then store it into an array?  It's probably going to have to be a multidimensional array for each slicercache.  Thoughts? Pointers? :D

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this. It will iterate through selected items in the State slicer.

```
For Each x In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_State").SlicerItems
If x.Selected = True Then
    a = x.Value
End If
```

Next x

Answer (score 1):

Snoobie, I would advice you to store slicer values in a dictionary in stead of an array. A dictionary is more flexible than an array as it has an `Exists` function. I will give you an example with a dictionary. Along the same lines you could make this work for an array.

```
Function slicerReader() As Dictionary
'add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library
Dim sc As SlicerCache
Dim si As SlicerItem
Dim dctStates As New Dictionary

Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_State")

For Each si In sc.SlicerItems
    If si.Selected Then
        dctStates.Add si.Value, si.Value
    End If
Next

Debug.Print dctStates.Exists("California")

Set slicerReader = dctStates
End Function
```